# CheckBoxList item checked Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I'm implementing a `checkboxlist`, if any Item is checked\unchecked, irrespective of which one was is it, I want to launch an event. How this could be done, Please help.

Comment: You could hook an event to every CheckedChanged  checkbox item. In this event you would get retrieve the combobox index to know which one you are dealing with

Comment: I am populating the checkboxlist dynamically as well :p

Comment: You can assign events in code behind as well.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"
            AutoPostBack="true"
            runat="server"/>

void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
         Label1.Text = "You selected " + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text +
                     " with a value of $" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value +
                     ".";
}
```

The same should work on `CheckBoxList` too.